# Prove that G is laying on K and find the ratio of AH to HB.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

We are given $Δ$ $ABC$ with $∠C = 90°$ and $AC > BC$. The circle K has a diameter CH (where CH is a height in $Δ$ $ABC$) and intersects with $AC$ in point $P$ and with $BC$ in point $Q$. If $PQ$ bisects $CG$, where $G$ is the centroid of $Δ$ $ABC$, prove that $G$ is laying on $K$ and find the ratio of $AH$ to $HB$.

[image]

You can find the diagram [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/zmZS3mTF)

Comment: Your diagram is not fully visible

Comment: A suggestion to improve readability: export your drawing with Geogebra as a png file and include it in your post directly.

Comment: Is $H$ the foot of the altitude from $C$ ?

Comment: Yes, H is the foot of the altitude from C.

Comment: No, $H$ is not a priori the altitude. One has to prove it.

Comment: @Futurologist: that is just your interpretation but the OP is claiming something else, namely that we know in advance that $CH$ is an altitude.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, the problem doesn't state it, the person who posted the problem does.

Comment: @Futurologist: technically speaking, "the problem" does not state either that $H\in AB$.

Comment: In the problem CH was an altitude but I missed to write it in the problem's description :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We have that $PQ$ is another diameter of the circle having $CH$ as a diameter and $CM\perp PQ$.
Assuming $BC=a<b=AC$, we have $CH=PQ=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $$CG=\frac{2}{3}CM=\frac{2}{3}AM=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{3}.$$
Moreover, since $CPQ$ is similar to $CBA$,
$$ CP = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}PQ = \frac{a^2 b}{a^2+b^2},\qquad CQ=\frac{ab^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$
If $G$ lies on the circumcircle of $CPQ$, by Ptolemy's theorem
$$ CG\cdot PQ = 2\,CP\cdot CQ $$
has to hold, hence
$$ \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{3}\cdot \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \frac{2a^3b^3}{(a^2+b^2)^2} $$
or
$$ (a^2+b^2)^2 = 6a^2 b^2 $$
that is a second degree equation in $r=\frac{b}{a}$, leading to:
$$ r=\frac{b}{a}=\color{red}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}. $$
The remaining part is easy: $\frac{HA}{HB}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}=r^2=\color{red}{2+\sqrt{3}}.$

Comment: Thank you! I just discovered that we can also use the power of the point M for the last part but your solution is appealing

Comment: Well, how do you know $CPQ$ is similar to $ABC$? The problem doesn't state the $CH$ is the altitude. You have to prove it. The rest is easy.

Comment: @Futurologist: the problem states that $CH$ is an altitude (see OP's comment) and the similarity follows from $CM\perp PQ$.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to prove that $CH$ is an altitude starting from what?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No it doesn't state that. It follows.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio follows from the fact that $PQ$ bisects $CG$ and the intersection point of $K$ and $AB$ is collinear with the center of $K$ and $C$.

Comment: @Futurologist: sorry, I had not read your answer. Ok, fine, we may either assume that $CH$ is an altitude or prove it through your approach. Then my solution finds the ratio $r$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes, the two solutions together make the final solution. Agreed.

Answer (score 4):

$CH$ is not assumed to be the altitude. One has to prove it. It follows from the assumptions of the problem. Here is how you can prove it.

If $PQ$ bisects orthogonally $CG$ then $G$ is the symmetric image of $C$ with respect to $PQ$ and triangles $PCQ$ and $PGQ$ are congruent. Hence $\angle \, PGQ = 90^{\circ} = \angle \, PCQ$ and since $\angle \, PGQ +  \angle \, PCQ = 180^{\circ}$ the quadrilateral $QCPG$ is inscribed in $K$. Since $CH$ is a diameter, the angles $\angle \, HQC = \angle \, HPC = 90^{\circ}$. Moreover, $\angle \, PCQ = 90^{\circ}$  so $PCQH$ is a rectangle inscribed in $K$ and the center of the triangle is the centroid of the rectangle. Hence, triangles $PHQ, \, PCQ$ and $PGQ$ are congruent. Segment $CE$ is a median in a right-angled triangle so $CE = BE = AE$ and the triangle $BCE$ is isosceles with $\angle \, EBC = \angle \, ECB = \angle \, GCQ$. By symmetry, $\angle \, GCQ = \angle \, CGQ$, and then $\angle \, CGQ = \angle \, CPQ$ as inscribed in $K$. We arrive at the conclusion that  $\angle \, ABC = \angle \, EBC = \angle \, GCQ = \angle \, CPQ$. Therefore triangles $ABC$ and $QPC$ are similar and since $CH$ is a diameter of the circle $K$ circumscribed around $QPC$, it is it's median while $CE$ is the median of $ABC$ leading to the conclusion that $\angle \, BCH = \angle \, ACE = \angle EAC = \angle \, BAC$. But this means that $\angle \, HBC + \angle \, BCH = \angle \, ABC + \angle \, BAC = 90^{\circ}$ which means that $CH$ is orthogonal to $AB$.